# Вставить видео YouTube из TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, плагин, tinymce

Когда через редактор tinyMCE вставляю видео с YouTube через раздел Insert/Media, в редакторе появляется превьюшка и видео воспроизводится. Но на сайте выводится только голый HTML такого рода

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ARuWid7UrPw" width="560" height="315"></iframe> </body>
</html>
```

Мой код настройки плагина

```
script>
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '.tinymce',
                mode : "exact",
                theme : "silver",
                plugins: "lists,advlist,anchor,autolink,autoresize,autosave,bbcode,charmap,code,codesample,directionality," +
                    "emoticons,fullpage,help,hr,image,imagetools,importcss,insertdatetime,legacyoutput,link,lists,media,mediaembed,nonbreaking," +
                    "noneditable,pagebreak,paste,preview,print,save,searchreplace,spellchecker,tabfocus,table,template,textpattern," +
                    "toc,visualblocks,visualchars,wordcount",
                toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | ' +
                    'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
                    'outdent indent | numlist bullist | link image anchor insertdatetime media |' +
                    '| emoticons pagebreak | paste searchreplace | toc visualblocks visualchars wordcount |',
                media_filter_html: false,
                extended_valid_elements: "+iframe[src|width|height|name|align|class]",
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел временное решение данной проблемы. Она кроется в саих views непосредственно. Вывод такого контента должен обрамляться следующей функцией

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($data->someData); ?>
```